# how to capture any query error for EF?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I am using EF for my project. When save any data change, there is a central place to capture any error by override SaveChanges like:

```
  public override int SaveChanges(System.Data.Objects.SaveOptions options)
        {           
            try
            {
                return base.SaveChanges(options);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
        //capture error here                
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

How to capture all query(either query with entity set based on linq or query with from SP) error in similar way?

Update: If it is not possible for all, is it possible to capture error in one place for all Stored Procedures?

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible on this level. You will not get queries or stored procedures which caused the error. It could be probably possible with [custom provider wrapper](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/EFProviderWrappers-c0b88f32) and custom error handling somewhere on that level but in that case you will be in reverse situation. You will know queries but you will not know source code which caused them (you will also not know entity sets involved without reverse engineering your mapping).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to monitor the queries on your data context, I suggest [EFProfiler](http://efprof.com). Although a commercial product, it will save you a lot of troubles down the road with its built-in warnings.